# JPEG - reading focal length from file

Tags: c++, jpeg, exif

While researching for a new camera, I thought it would be interesting to generate an overview over the most common settings I have used in the past in my pictures. I'm mainly interested in retrieving the focal length used in the picture. Though aperture / iso / shutterspeed would be welcome, too.

Having used different cameras for the past 10 years though, I would need to convert it too a 35mm equivalent format for comparison. I know this is a function of the sensor size, specifically sensor crop factor times focal length.

Searcing around I didn't manage to find a jpeg file format header. I learned you can find most of those at a site called wotsit.org but apparantly I can't download anything from there. I know next to nothing about jpeg files, but I'm pretty sure they use exif format to hold image metadata, that I'm looking for.

http://www.exif.org/Exif2-1.PDF, page 49, shows focal length is stored as a rational* number, somewhere. But I'm having a hard time grasping the structure and applying it in code. Besides, to calculate the equivalent 35mm ratio, i would have to know the camera's sensor size, which i can't find in that documentation.

Would someone be able to give a hint / point me in the direction to the actual structure of the jpeg / exif file? I will be using C++ for this project. I know this must be possible, windows shows the 35mm eqv. of my pictures.

*This seems to be two ulongs which represent a fraction, that, when divided, gives the     focal length?

TL;DR: How to extract the focal length and sensor size from a jpeg file in order to compute the 35mm equivalent focal length?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to write your own app for this? The Exiftool command line app will give you the focal length http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Comment: I didn't think it would be such a huge task retrieving two numbers from a file, but it seems so. Maybe if exiftool accept scripted commands / work on dirs ill use it, checking it out.

Comment: It should be possible to get the command line tool to do what you want (maybe with a bit of shell scripting), if not it's also a perl library, but I doubt you'll need that.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're purpose is to learn how to read these images I would suggest using a library such as [libexif](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I have no interest in doing so. I might end up using this, was really hoping not to have such a huge library for doing such a little thing.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer: http://www.exiv2.org/

Comment: Same as the upper comment, but thanks. Nice documentation, scanning through it. Have you used it before?

Comment: @Shaggi: 1) My answer was the first, and 2) not quite the same, libexif is old and plain C, libexiv2 is new, C++ and easier to use :)

Comment: @Shaggi: and yes, I have used it a bit.